Is there a way to differentiate whether the device has face id or fingerprint in Kotlin
I'm trying to find a way to check if the Android device has fingerprint auth of face id auth.
In Kotlin, I found a solution that is working well for fingerprint
private fun hasFingerprintAuth(): Boolean {
    val fingerprintManager = getSystemService(Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE) as android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager?
    return fingerprintManager?.isHardwareDetected == true && fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()
}

Using the method "invokeMethod" from MethodChannel, I get the result in Flutter.
But I researched a lot and could't find a way to detect only if a device has faceID auth. It seems that you can check if device has biometrics, but not this specific one That I need.
Is there a way to get this information in Kotlin? Or even in Flutter?

For Android devices, there isn't a direct API to check specifically for Face ID like there is for fingerprint authentication. However, I think we can use the BiometricManager class, which was introduced in Android 10, to get more information about the available biometric options. I have a Kotlin function that attempts to determine if face authentication is available:
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import androidx.biometric.BiometricManager
import androidx.biometric.BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG

fun hasFaceAuth(context: Context): Boolean {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    val biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(context)
    
    // Check if the device supports biometric authentication
    val canAuthenticate = biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_STRONG)
    
    if (canAuthenticate == BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS) {
        // Device supports biometric authentication, now check for face unlock
        val packageManager = context.packageManager
        return packageManager.hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.biometrics.face")
    }
}
return false

}
Please note that this method isn't foolproof, as device manufacturers might implement face recognition differently. Some devices might support face unlock without exposing it through this system feature.

Hey bro, thanks. I will try this later :)
